# Android HTTPRequest on ICS fails :(

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Here is my sample code to make http request but it fails to do so. Here is the error log i see in LogCat. http://pastebin.com/56AL8Dxu
I have also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in manifest. Please help me..is that really that hard to make a simple http request in Android ? I am from .Net background learning Android development.

```
void testHTTP()
 {
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com");

  try {
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

   //System.out.println("response protocol version: " + response.getProtocolVersion());
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the Logcat log:

> 04-29 19:59:53.072: E/AndroidRuntime(546): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You perform `testHTTP()`, which involves networking on main thread, which is not allowed. Move it to a background thread, or use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: So it means that any http web request ALWAYS needs to be run in background thread and not main thread even if i want it to run it that way?

Comment: Yes, this is a very common concept of UI programming in general - any heavy processing task (and moreover, any non-UI related task) should be performed on the background.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet You are right that any heavy lifting should be done on a background thread but you can very well do Http Request on UI thread.

Comment: @blackcrow - any HTTP connection should be handled in a background thread / NIO. any other attempt is a bad practice, and it's better for all of us that such exception is thrown.

Comment: Guys, this is just a test app. I will use AsyncTask /background thread. But for now how do i make it run ?

Comment: @Anil - no shortcuts, Move it to background, it should take two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Binyamin Sharet is correct, I quote from Android Documentation

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK (3.0) or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that its ONLY for 3.0 and above.